# The de-serialization relies loading a pickle file

Tags: python, pickle, py-langchain, faiss

I got this error:

> The de-serialization relies loading a pickle file. Pickle files can be modified to deliver a malicious payload that results in execution of arbitrary code on your machine.You will need to set `allow_dangerous_deserialization` to `True` to enable deserialization. If you do this, make sure that you trust the source of the data. For example, if you are loading a file that you created, and no that no one else has modified the file, then this is safe to do. Do not set this to `True` if you are loading a file from an untrusted source (e.g., some random site on the internet.).

Answer (score 10):

Use following import

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
```

and

```
new_db = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings,allow_dangerous_deserialization=True)
```

should fix this. This is a feature to prevent any dangerous executions by default from a .pkl file

Comment: Nice one! Just getting into LLMs, you saved me ton of work with this solution. Keep it up!